# Module over a ring satisfying ACC

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $R$ be a ring that satisfies ACC on the set of its left ideals and
>   $M$ be a finite generated $R$-module. Prove that every submodule of
>   $M$ is finitely generated.

I know that if $M$ satisfies ACC condition then every submodules of it are finite generated. I only want to show that $M$ satisfies ACC condition.

Help me some hints.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *Hint:* Rings meeting the ACC condition are called *Noetherian* rings. Prove that a ring is Noetherian iff all of its ideals are finitely generated. Then prove that a module meets the ACC condition iff all its submodules are finitely generated.

Comment: I've done the first part of you hint. For the second, can you explain more precise?

Comment: A module that meets the ACC conditon is called Noetherian module. Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

First try to show following fact: For any exact sequence $A\rightarrow M\rightarrow B$, $M$ satisfies ACC iff $A$ and $B$ satisfy ACC. Use it to prove that finitely generated free modules satisfy ACC.

- There is an exact sequence $R^{n-1}\rightarrow R^n\rightarrow R$. $R$ satisfy ACC. Assume that $R^{n-1}$ satisfy ACC too then by induction so does $R^n$.

Now notice that module $M$ is finitely generated iff there is a finitely generated free module $F$ and a surjection $f:F\rightarrow M$.

- If $M$ has generators $\{m_1,...,m_n\}$ then there is a surjection $f:R^n\rightarrow M$ defined on base $f:x_i\mapsto m_i$

Use fact again to prove that $M$ satisfy ACC.

- There is an exact sequence $\ker(f)\rightarrow R^n\rightarrow M$.

Suppose that there is submodule $N\subset M$ which is not finitely generated. Enumerate its elements then we have sequence of submodules $(m_1)\subset (m_1,m_2)...$ It is easy to see that this sequence will not stabilise.

Comment: The first fact you told is Lemma $4.1.5$ of http://modular.math.washington.edu/129/ant/html/node11.html

Comment: Can you explain more precise?

Comment: What is unclear exactly is unclear for you?

Comment: All except the first fact ("For any exact sequence $A\rightarrow M\rightarrow B$, $M$ satisfies ACC iff $A$ and $B$ satisfy ACC") and the final ("Suppose that ... stabilise")

Comment: This post improve your hint http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306546/specific-proof-that-any-finitely-generated-r-module-over-a-noetherian-ring-is?rq=1